# C++ GCC - Unable to include ctime, cstring or cstdlib

Tags: c++, gcc, include

So I have created a simple function to get the current date and time. It works fine when I am testing it in Visual Studio on my Windows machine.

These are the directories included in order for my date time function to work:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Adding these to the top of my c++ program in Visual Studio will work fine, but when I try to compile it using GCC on my VPS server, I get this error

```
main.c:12:17: error: ctime: No such file or directory
main.c:13:19: error: cstring: No such file or directory
main.c:14:19: error: cstdlib: No such file or directory
```

Here is how I compile my C++ program on my VPS server using GCC:

```
gcc main.c -o bin/main `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -std=c99 -lpthread;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc` is not the compiler for c++. you need to use `g++`.

[See a live example here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbb3bd86e16756eb)

You will also need to review your flags and `-std` type. You are trying to compile a c++ file as c.

Answer (score 3):

gcc is a C compiler. To compile C++ code you need to use g++.

Your source file should also have a .cpp or .cxx extension.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is of C++; however, there are 2 mistakes out of your code that are leading to these errrors:

Firstly, your file with the code should be named with a `.cpp` or `.cxx` extension at the end of it. Right now, it is `main.c`, and `.c` is an extension for a file of C code, not C++. So, you should change your file name to `main.cpp`.

Secondly, put simply, **gcc** is a compiler meant for C code. Your code, once again, is C++. Therefore, use **g++** in your command, not **gcc**.